# ZAP error: Web Browser XSS Protection is not enabled

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, zap

While scanning my application by ZAP, I am getting below error.

```
Web Browser XSS Protection is not enabled, or is disabled by the configuration of the 'X-XSS-Protection' HTTP response header on the web server
    CWE ID: 933
    WASC ID: 14
```

The error resolves when I enabled a header property 'X-XSS-Protection' by adding a  property in web.config file.

But as my requirement I need to do this from webpage itself.

Is there any way to add header from server or client site?

I have tried with below code, but not working.

```
Response.Headers.Add("X-XSS-Protection", "1");

HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers["X-XSS-Protection"] = "1";
```

Comment: In which event and page you are trying to add this? and are you getting any error while debugging it?

Comment: You could also perhaps use the .htaccess file to include this setting?